# Why doesn't my SVG background-image work?

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image

I placed a green PNG image as background to a div and it looks like this:

[image: working background image]

I used a CSS hack in order to keep the text inside the green background. So this is my code for that section:

```css
#aboutprocess {
    background: url("../img/tech_bg.png") no-repeat left top;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
#aboutprocess .container {
    padding-top: 32.6316%;
    position: relative;
}
#aboutprocess .row {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#aboutprocess p {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="aboutprocess">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 ">
                <p class="text-center">Our agile team continuously delivers working software and empowers your organization to embrace changing requirements.</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link center-block white" role="link" type="submit" name="op" value="Link 2">about our process</button>
            </div>
            <!--end col-md-8 col-md-offset-2-->
        </div>
        <!--end row -->
    </div>
    <!--end container-->
</section>
<!--end aboutprocess-->
```

I want to replace the PNG with an SVG file, and the only thing that I changed in the CSS is the file extension:

```css
#aboutprocess {
    background: url("../img/tech_bg.svg") no-repeat left top;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But when I preview this in browser, I can't see the background anymore:

[image: non-working background image]

What am I doing wrong? You can see the demo page with the PNG background image [here](http://dolm.ragne.me/).

Here's a [Dropbox link to the SVG file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qe9cmc4nck2i7l/tech_bg.svg?dl=0).

Comment: Could you post your SVG file as well.

Comment: I updated my original post with a Dropbox link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few potential solutions here.

- Revisit how you created the SVG. The software you use and the method you generate it with (e.g. in Illustrator) matter greatly. There's a pretty specific way of doing it correctly.
  <sub>**This was the solution for OP; see comments for specifics**</sub>

- Making absolutely positively sure that `tech_bg.svg` is in the directory that it's supposed to be (the `img` folder) and that it's spelled exactly the same as it is in the text editor, including case sensitivity of the filename and file extension. GitHub certainly takes extension case sensitivity literally and I've had problems uploading SVG files for that same reason (.svg vs .SVG).
- Increasing the `z-index` of `#aboutprocess`, particularly if your text really has disappeared (I'm assuming it's still there, just white, but try highlighting it to make sure). Play around with the other CSS values nearby like no-repeat, left, top, etc, too.
- Try clearing your browser cache and refreshing once, and try other browsers too. Also, if by some chance you happen to be using IE8 and below or Android 2.3 and below, that would definitely be the cause; they don't support SVGs in background-images.

It's a tough question to answer definitively since we can't be there testing it with you on your local machine, which is where the inconsistency is happening.

Comment: I actually exported this green background as svg from Photoshop. Maybe I should try Illustrator instead? It crossed my mind that maybe that might be the issue but why should Photoshop's svg be any different. Or is it? I'll give it a try.

Comment: Photoshop has historically been a raster based graphics editor that cannot produce true SVGs, whereas Illustrator is a vector based graphics editor and is designed specifically to produce true SVG's.

Comment: Ok, I tried the same thing in Illustrator. No luck. I made several other SVG files today that work just fine, so it can't be that I'm generating this wrong.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally pressed enter. I was about to say that this may have changed some in the latest photoshop releases (Photoshop CC), but after looking online, I doubt it. I think photoshop CC's 'save as SVG' function is more for converting shapes, not png images. Converting a PNG to a true vector graphic is very unconventional anyways. But it is possible and it can look decent, particularly since yours is a solid color and not a picture of people or a building. If any program should do this, it's illustrator. Look up how to do it. You'll use the 'Live Trace' button. Could be ur problem.

Comment: Hmm, it is a very odd problem. If I were you and I had exhausted all the options above (cache clearing, z-index, proper file location/name, true vector image, using different browser), I may even try a git push to a gh-pages branch and see what it looks like when uploaded. Could just be your local machine being finicky with the SVG.

Comment: @KyleVassella actually if you open that svg in a browser you will see that it's not solid color at all. Also to OP , you could just put that base64 code straight into your css. Tho i don't think there's any point doing that, in this case.

Comment: OP: If you are dragging a PNG into Photoshop and exporting as SVG, Photoshop will give it an .SVG extension, but your photo will almost certainly be re-rasterized on export. So you're adding the .SVG extension without making your file an actual functioning SVG (purpose of SVG is to make image infinitely scaleable). Photoshop is not designed to generate SVG - it's only designed to work with them since it has to be able to work with Illustrator files. If you want to actually create a real SVG, you MUST use Illustrator and use the Live Trace button. Currently you're using SVG with no benefit.

Comment: Granted, this doesn't solve your original glitch of the image not showing up at all when your other photoshop 'svg' files did. But it does address another important issue - you're needlessly using large (slow) SVG files with no benefit. They are supposed to be 'scaleable' vector graphics but the ones saved out of PS are raster (pixel) based, rather than vector (line) based. Actually converting a saved PNG to SVG is a big deal, takes big processing power and decent amount of time after you click the Live Trace button. Not as simple as saving as a diff file extension unfortunately.

Comment: You were right. I tried again.I exported the background image as PNG from Photoshop. I placed it in Illustrator, used Image Trace as High Fidelity Photo and saved it as SVG. And now it works fine. Previously I hadn't used the trace option. So thank you! :) But it addresses another issue. The tracing quality is not so good as it should. So I should probably stick to PNG anyhow. I just don't like the rough edges it leaves and I thougt that SVG would give a better result.

Comment: I'm glad it showed up for you. You could play around with Illustrator's Trace Options (there are tutorials on YouTube), but I think a better way is to fix the rough edges in PhotoShop (do it to your original PNG file, no need to save as SVG). Using the Quick Selection Tool, select all of the green area. Then near the top of the PhotoShop window click the Refine Edge button. Finally adjust the 'Smooth' slider until you (possibly) get a better look. If smooth doesn't give you a cleaner edge, perhaps try the other sliders or a combo of sliders, but I think smooth alone should do a nice job.

Comment: Last thing - if you have a problem with the 'Smooth' slider distorting the already clean left and right edges of your green bar, use the method I described above but instead of selecting the green area, try selecting the white areas and smooth those instead (if green is already selected, CMD+Shift+i (mac) or CTRL+Shift+i (Windows) will quickly inverse the selection to the white areas).

Answer (score 9):

Browsers will NOT display SVG files if the web server transfers it with the wrong "content-type" header.

If your web service is returning `application/octet-stream` or `text/xml`, the image will not work properly, in spite of the SVG being transferred correctly and the SVG file itself being fine.

The correct media type for SVG is `image/svg+xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem is not always came from the css. Please have a try to add the following line to your **.htaccess**, so the server can recognize svg files from your css file (*background: url("../img/tech_bg.svg") no-repeat left top;*), Insert this line:

```
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg|bmp|png|css|pdf|swf|mp3|mp4|3gp|flv|avi|rm|mpeg|wmv|xml|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|csv|ppt|pptx|zip|rar|mov)$ index.php
```

No need to have so many rules as above but depends on what you need for the format you would like to have on your site, but for your current question here, please make sure there is "**svg**" in the rule of your .htaccess file.

It works, try it!  :)

Comment: please check your browser's network tab or debugging console before going with this solution. If you aren't seeing errors with the request then this is not going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.pic {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("../img/tech_bg.svg");
    }
```

dont foreget dots and /   --->   ../
not background  ---> background-image:
and dont forget clear browser history and cash

```
<div class="pic"></div>
```

Comment: Please have a look at the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the color of the SVG was the same as the color of the background, so you couldn't see it.

Comment: While useful information;  this is perhaps more of a comment than an answer here as it currently stands.