# SET background-image to a div in css

Tags: html, css

Whats wrong with following code, why is background image not showing:

**HTML**

```
<div class="logo"> E  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("/banner.svg");
}
```

No rocket science, by using Brackets editor, simply trying to add background-image to a div. Image file is in the same folder as .html and .css file.

Comment: no visible issue. are you sure about the image path ? /banner.svg vs ./banner.svg

Comment: Are you sure about the image path and name?

Comment: @jeremy-denis: I've tried both /banner.svg & ./banner.svg .. whatever differences they make, no difference made to my situation.

Comment: @ShahriarHossain: Yes. image path and name are correct. If you have a method in your mind for testing that out, please mention. Thanks

Comment: @Roy: No your link doesn't answer my question. I have tried that solution with no success.

Comment: Could you share your site structure ? in which folder is your image and where is the html and css that load it

Comment: @jeremy-denis https://ibb.co/Yfcv364

Comment: Does this answer your questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023616/why-doesnt-my-svg-background-image-work

Comment: Can you open the network inspector and see where it is trying to load the image from? You should see a 404 (or similar) error and the path it is trying to go to.

Comment: Can you confirm that the div actually has a width and height by using the inspector?

Comment: @jeremy-denis: yes it is the svg causing error. I replaced .svg file with a .jpg and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

i assume your image-link is wrong.
You could try to colorize the background to see if its really image related:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow, blue);
```

Comment: sure your linear-gradient is showing up on the div. why the hell is my given path wrong and why the hell is whole web is filled with the "WRONG PATH" answer?

Comment: @Oxin you can be mad all you want but that doesn't change the reality of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your image path maybe wrong

You better try this

### CSS

```
.logo {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("./banner.svg");
}
```

Comment: your solution isnt working

Comment: Try using vh instead of % in height

Answer (score 0):

As your image is in the same folder as your code you don't need that /

```
<div class="logo"> E  </div>
CSS

.logo
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("banner.svg");
}
```

Comment: not as easy as you have put it sir. Not working.

Comment: It works for me so I suspect your banner.svg is not in the same folder as your html code OR your svg is corrupt in some way.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no problem in the code. The url to the image must be wrong. Check the path again.
NOTE:

- / is the root of the current drive;
- ./ is the current directory;
- ../ is the parent of the current directory.

Comment: all 3 options not working

Comment: @Oxin those are not options. They are examples of different path behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks okay but you might want to check the image URL.
"/banner.svg" means the image is in the same directory as the CSS file, if it's not then correct the image URL. You might also want to check the image extension is it really svg or png?
If you think the URL is correct then try adding a background color of red to the logo class and you'll know where the issue lies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `background-color` property is easily set on div but `background-image` is unnecessarily not working. I have made sure to check .svg extension as well as its placement in the same folder as .cs file. no fruits

Answer (score 0):

Double check your image path and consider adding:

```
.logo {
  background-image: url(banner.svg);
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ah, if you run it just on a static HTML but not in a server, you can modify like this:

```
 background-image: url("banner.svg");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: dont know what u r trying to say